# I can't get a value from a PHP array...?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm writing a script to retrieve the scores from an [osu!](http://osu.ppy.sh/) beatmap. The script uses the osu! API, which can be found [here](http://osu.ppy.sh/api). I've obtained a valid API key, and got the info from the website. My project can be found here: [failosu!](http://projectnebula.org/failosu).

This script is called by AJAX, and the variable s is passed via POST.

My problem is with the returned array.

In the following snippet (not really, it's pretty much my entire script), I make a request for the beatmap information first. In doing this, I am passing a variable, s (beatmap set ID), to the server, and trying to get the variable b (beatmap ID).

However, whenever I call `$d1['beatmap_id']`, it doesn't return anything to the main page. Instead, my AJAX script runs the error function rather than the success function. Does anyone know what my problem is?

```
if($_POST['id']) {
    $s = $_POST['id'];
    $k = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $u0 = "https://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_beatmaps?k=".$k."&s=".$s;
    $d0 = json_decode(file_get_contents($u0));
    $d1 = get_object_vars($d0[0]);
    $b = $d1["beatmap_id"];

    // THE CODE STOPS WORKING HERE FOR SOME REASON ????

    $u = "https://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_scores?k=".$k."&b=".$b."&m=0";
    echo $u;

    $d = json_decode(file_get_contents($u));
    for($i=0;$i<count($d);$i++) {
        echo "<li>".$i." ".$d[$i]['username']."</li>";
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what's wrong? Do you need me to tell you more information about my code?

Comment: what does `var_dump($d0);` display?

Comment: @dbf [here's a screenshot](http://puu.sh/6c0HB.jpg); it works until i add that one line, which is the most crucial line :I

Comment: does `var_dump($d0[0]->beatmap_id);` give you direct access to the property?

Comment: i can access the property, and it returns the correct value, but i can't set that value to `$b` for some reason

Comment: PROTIP: `json_decode($json, TRUE)`.  The 2nd parameter set to TRUE will give you an associative array.  Then you don't need `get_object_vars`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yea I suggested that in a comment I previously deleted, but it doesn't really make sense because `$d0[0]` is an `stdClass` and it has valid properties. It should return an array with the property names as indices. Code being used above seems to be valid .. Doesn't really make sense why `$d[0]->beatmap_id` is accessible but `(get_object_vars($d0[0]))['beatmap_id'];` is not ..

Comment: @dbf: I guess, but that just seems like a simpler/cleaner option.

Comment: @RocketHazmat true ;)

Comment: Right way to get $d1[0]->beatmap_id. the another issue could be you have five different beatmap_id values and you are using only one. you might need use the loop to get use all five values of may be just need to use beatmapset_id field which is unique

Comment: good observation, but i'm only using the first beatmap_id, and they're in different stdClass objects